# Converting matrix-like string into matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, text

I want to convert a string from a .txt file into an actual matrix that i can use in my code. The .txt file looks like this:

```
Version:1

Matrix1
[ 0.83568616  2.15352694 -4.4027591  -1.74058247 -0.42605484 -0.21766954]
[-1.0363443  -1.07584464  0.67931046  1.82348912  1.71141435 -0.40177167]
[-0.49192281  0.83897739 -0.97685038  1.3442258   1.91058796 -0.46493662]
[ 0.42825634 -0.58257726  2.0370751  -1.11937523 -3.81475336  2.66557629]
```

I have tried this different ways, but here's what I currently have:

```
f = open("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Output_data/output_data1.txt", "r")
string1 = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
string1 = string1[3:7]
Matrix1 = np.array(string1)
for elem in Matrix1:
    elem = float(elem)
```

This doesn't work because an (elem) of Matrix1 is a string(including the brackets).

Is there an easy way to convert this into a Matrix I can use?

Comment: You could just take each line `L`, clip off the brackets `L[1:-1]` and split them into "words" `L[1:-1].split()` each of these words you can convert to float etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start of your code...

```
f = open("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Output_data/output_data1.txt", "r")
string1 = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
string1 = string1[3:7]
```

so far so good, now we want to do something different that, using your style, can be written like this

```
# strip the [] brackets
string1 = [x[1:-1] for x in string1]

# data is a list of lists of floating point numbers
data = [[float(f) for f in x.split()] for x in string1]

# a list of lists is almost an array, the final step is
Matrix1 = np.array(data)
```

In short

```
mat = np.array([[float(x) for x in l.strip()[1:-1].split()] for l in f.readlines()[3:7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.matrix` accepts strings as argument but special format, i.e, no brackets and new line character should be semicolon, so if you remove the square brackets and replace new line character with `;`, you can use `numpy.matrix` to read them in:

```
s = """[ 0.83568616  2.15352694 -4.4027591  -1.74058247 -0.42605484 -0.21766954]
[-1.0363443  -1.07584464  0.67931046  1.82348912  1.71141435 -0.40177167]
[-0.49192281  0.83897739 -0.97685038  1.3442258   1.91058796 -0.46493662]
[ 0.42825634 -0.58257726  2.0370751  -1.11937523 -3.81475336  2.66557629]"""
​
import numpy as np    ​
mat = np.matrix(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('\n', ';'))
​
mat
# matrix([[ 0.83568616,  2.15352694, -4.4027591 , -1.74058247, -0.42605484, -0.21766954],
#         [-1.0363443 , -1.07584464,  0.67931046,  1.82348912,  1.71141435, -0.40177167],
#         [-0.49192281,  0.83897739, -0.97685038,  1.3442258 ,  1.91058796, -0.46493662],
#         [ 0.42825634, -0.58257726,  2.0370751 , -1.11937523, -3.81475336, 2.66557629]])
```

---

For your case, you can try to load the data in line by line (there probably is a better way) and add them to an empty matrix:

```
string1 = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
string1 = string1[3:7]
mat = np.empty((0, 6))
for string in string1:
    mat = np.vstack([mat, np.matrix(string.strip('[]'))])
```